# Get limit of the human body in Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect.toolbox

I need to resolve this situation:

Need to get the ends of the body of a person through the Kinect sensor. Thus, need the X, Y coordinates of each point. I have logic to it, which is move the skeleton points to the end of the body of the person, but do not know how to carry out such an operation.

Here is a picture of some of the points I wanted to get.

[image]

They all start from the points of starting points, which are: `head`, `sholder hight`, `left sholder`, `hip hight` and `left hip`. Please help me. I'm sorry for the text, I do not speak English. I'm using google translator to for help.

Comment: Can you post your image on a site that isn't trying to scam me into thinking I won a contest as soon as I click your link?

Comment: @dman2306 I could not post the picture for not having enough reputation. This is my first question in the forum. I'm just asking for help to the mentioned problem, I have no need to mislead anyone. Just click the link to see that there is nothing more, just an image.

Comment: @dman2306 this is another link http://i.imgur.com/C57ZwXE.jpg

Comment: @Zach Morgan wasn't suggesting you were misleading. It was the sites' fault not yours

Comment: In your image, you show the ends of the hips, but it doesn't continue to the arms, is that your intention?  Or do you want it to cover the whole body, like this? http://i.imgur.com/dtLsj63.jpg

Comment: @GregT-MN Getting the edge of the hips would be enough for me. Later could try to get the other end regions of the human body. For now, the points shown in the image satisfy me. I really need to solve this problem.